# PHP preg_replace replacing line break

Tags: php, regex

When renumbering an array using

```
$arr=array_values($arr); // Renumber array
```

I realized that a line break is being introduced into one of the array strings, which I don't want.

My string is going from:

Property
Type

to Property

Type

In any case I am using:

```
$newelement = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9\s\s+]/", " ", $element);
```

already to remove unwanted characters prior to database insertion, so I tried to change it to:

```
 $newelement = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9\s\s+'<br>''<br>''/n''/cr']/", " ", $element);
```

But there is no change, and the ?line feed/line break/carriage return is still there.

Am I doing the preg_replace call correctly?

Comment: line breaks are \n or \r or \r\n depending on the operating system. `str_replace (array('\r\n', '\n', '\r'), ' ', $text)`

Comment: You need to fix the underlying problem instead of trying to patch it up; `array_values` does not change the values, see this example: http://codepad.org/Mhbzjkl8

Answer (score 43, accepted):

That preg looks a bit complicated. And then you have ^ in the beginning as *not* A-Z... or linefeed. So you don't want to replace linefeed?

How about

```
$newelement = preg_replace("/[\n\r]/", "", $element);
```

or

```
$newelement = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z ]/", "", $element);
```

\s also matches linefeed (\n).

Comment: For the first alternative `/\\[nr]/` would be a more exact pattern. Without those backslashes escaped it's going to replace the letters 'n' or 'r'.

Answer (score 6):

This should work too:

```
// char(32) is whitespace
// For CR
$element = strtr($element, chr(13), chr(32));

// For LF
$element = strtr($element, chr(10), chr(32));
```

Answer (score 4):

This thing worked for me.

```
preg_replace("/\r\n\r\n|\r\r|\n\n/", "<br />", $element);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a hack, but you can do something like this:

```
    $email_body_string  = preg_replace("/\=\r\n$/", "", $email_body_string);
```

The replacement says find a line that ends with an equals sign and has the standard carriage return and line feed characters afterwards. Replace those characters with nothing ("") and the equals sign will disappear. The line below it will be pulled up to join the first line.

Now, this implies that you will never have a line that ends with an equals sign, which is a risk. If you want to do it one better, check the line length where the wrap (with the equals sign) appears. It's usually about 73 characters in from the beginning of the line. Then you could say:

```
    if (strlen(equals sign) == 73)
       $email_body_string  = preg_replace("/\=\r\n$/", "", $email_body_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Most simply, call `preg_replace()` on your flat array of values and use `\v+` to target each occurrence each occurrence of one or more vertical whitespaces. (Demo)

```
$arr = [
    'Property Type',
    'Property

Type',
    'new
    
    
    
    
lines

again'
];

var_export(
    preg_replace('/\v+/', ' ', $arr)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'Property Type',
  1 => 'Property Type',
  2 => 'new lines again',
)
```