# str_replace("\r\n") replaces twice, while str_replace("\n") replaces once

Tags: php, string, function, replace

I've got an html form that generates BBCode which is a modified form of html used in some online message boards.  The biggest difference with BBCode is that it uses brackets on tags instead of the traditional less than/greater than symbols (such as [br] for example).

One of my form elements is a multiline textbox that can send text such as the following:

Red

Orange

Black

There's an \r\n at the end of each line that doesn't get passed to my output so that I get:

RedOrangeBlack

I'm using the following code to replace the \r\n with [br]

```
$_description = stripslashes($_POST['description']);
$movie_description = str_replace("\r\n","[br]",$_description);
```

The output is now:

Black[br][br]Orange[br][br]Red

Which is one [br] too many.

If I switch the str_replace function to:

```
$movie_description = str_replace("\n","[br]",$_description);
```

I get Black [br]Orange [br]Red which is better, but now there's a space in the front of line's 2 and 3.  If I replace \r instead of \n the results are similar.

How do I get an output that looks like:

Black[br]Orange[br]Red

Comment: I'm still dubious of the observations, but I've edited the title to reflect the claim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two newlines, so replace them both

```
$movie_description = str_replace("\r\n\r\n","[br]",$_description);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$movie_description = preg_replace("/(\r?\n)+/","[br]",$_description);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your input has multiple `\r\n` sequences instead of just one at the end. I.e. you have a blank line between the words.

To fix that, you need to decide exactly what you want to do if there's only one, or more than two.

Supposing you want just one [br] in all cases, I'd suggest using a command that has the ability to do wildcards such as preg_replace.

There's some examples in [php preg_replace replacing line break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498337/php-preg-replace-replacing-line-break)

Answer (score 0):

Use preg_replace to replace one or more line break by only one `[br]`

```
$str = 'Red

Orange

Black';
$str = preg_replace('/\R+/', '[br]', $str);
echo $str;
```

**Output:**

```
Red[br]Orange[br]Black
```

`\R` stands for any kind of line break.