# Can't retrieve in correct form data from SQL in TinyMCE

Tags: php, jquery, tinymce

I want to create an editor with TinyMCE and I have an error when I want to add content from SQL.

The function inside `tinymce.init` is:

```
setup: function (editor) {
  editor.on('init', function (e) {
    editor.setContent('<?php print_r($contract->anexa_la_contract);?>');
  });
}
```

It needs to load the content. Instead, it gives this error in the console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: '' string literal contains an unescaped line
> break

This is the result from the error:

```
editor.on('init', function (e) {
  editor.setContent('<ul>
    <li>sda</li>
    <li>sda</li>
    <li>sda</li>
    <li>ds</li>
  </ul>');
  });
}
```

Any advice on how I should fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the line breaks, I don't think you really need them

```
editor.setContent('<?php echo preg_replace("/[\n\r|\r\n|\r|\n]/m", "", $contract->anexa_la_contract); ?>');
```

more info and example you can find in

[PHP preg_replace replacing line break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498337/php-preg-replace-replacing-line-break/35897430)

[preg_replace() and \n in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579636/preg-replace-and-n-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

try to quite some regexp black magic like:

```
editor.setContent('<?php print_r($contract->anexa_la_contract);?>'.replace(/(?!\B"[^"]*)\\n(?![^"]*"\B)/g, '\n'));
```